# RoR routing error, No route matches [POST]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a beginner in Rails, This is the rails guide blog app. After submitting the form I get *No route matches [POST] "/articles/new"* which is weird because as you can see from the routes below, articles/new doesn't have a post.

Controller file:

```
def new
    @article = Article.new
end

def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
        redirect_to @article
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
private
    def article_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end
```

Routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get 'welcome/index'
    root 'welcome#index'
    resources :articles
```

Routes:

```
Prefix        Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)     welcome#index
         root GET    /                            welcome#index
     articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
              POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
  new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
 edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
      article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
              PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
              PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
              DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
```

[EDIT] Here's the form also

```
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :title %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :text %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :text %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%=f.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you show your form .....

Comment: Where do you get this error from? Please show the exact line (I guess it's none of those)

Comment: you're posting to `/articles/new`, instead of `/articles`

Comment: are you still getting same error . bcoz your form looks ok. it should go to articles create action.

Comment: This seems right. Are you running in development mode? Do you have `config.cache_classes = false`? Have you tried restarting the server?

Comment: Try changing it to `<%= form_for @article, url: articles_path do |f| %>`

Answer (score 0):

Change the form helper to:

`<%= form_for @article do |f| %>`

You don't need to specify the url if it's the default controller action (articles#create)

Other option:

```
<%= form_for Article.new do |f| %>
```

Comment: I did change it and removed the url, however it sill gives me the same error.

Comment: In which file do you have the form?

Comment: app/views/articles/new.html.erb

Comment: Did you try `Article.new`? This definitely has to work, if everything else is like you described!

Comment: Yes I did, could there be another problem I'm unaware of?

Comment: Do you have the article model? Could you copy and paste the complete error message? You can find it at the bottom of your `development.log` file.

Comment: Yes I have the article model. Here's the complete error message:
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/articles/new"):

Comment: Could you post your app to github? I really want to find out what the problem is!

Answer (score 0):

As you're new to Rails, let me give you some ideas

---

[**form_for**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for)

The problem with this is down to your use of `form_for`

`form_for` basically creates a form out of an ActiveRecord object - allowing you to populate various attributes & other elements of the object with a standard method.

Part of this is to create a [`url`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for) component for the form, which will be built from the `model_name` attribute of your object. Typically, you'll populate the `form_for` with a pure ActiveRecord object; but as you've just used a symbol, it's going to cause a problem when looking for the `url` in the non-existent object:

--

**Fix**

The way to fix this is populate the `form_for` with an ActiveRecord object:

```
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
```

You've already done *most* of the work for this - in your controller, you have to declare the `@article` variable in the `new` and `create` actions:

```
#app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
Class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
   def new
       @article = Article.new
   end

   def create
       @article = Article.new(article_params)
       @article.save
   end

   private

   def article_params
       parmas.require(:article).permit(:your, :attributes)
   end
end
```

Comment: The docs you link to suggest a symbol is fine - in fact that's the first example they give

Comment: I know, I was going to mention that. I don't know why they have that in the docs - in my experience, it always causes problems

Comment: Hmmm - can you post your updated code by any chance?